# Saving checkbox values to firestore? android studio in kotlin

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, kotlin, checkbox

is it possible to save the values of checkboxes checked by users in firestore firebase?

Comment: The state of a checkbox can be stored as a boolean. What have you tried to do?

Comment: Please edit your question and show us what you have tried and what exactly in that doesn't work the way you expect.